# I can't find the database(using sequel pro) migrated on homestead after I did the "php artisan migrate" command

Tags: mysql, laravel, homestead, sequelpro

I just new up a laravel project on homestead. I already ssh on my virtual machine, edited the .env file and run "php artisan migrate". it clearly ran with out issue. Now I want to view the database tables created using sequel pro. I can connect with the database but the tables are not there.

Here's my database .env entry:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Homestead set up:

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/site
      to: /home/vagrant/site

sites:
    - map: homestead.test
      to: /home/vagrant/site/rm/public

databases:
    - homestead
```

Sequel Pro:

```
Name: homestead
Host: 127.0.0.1
Username: homestead
Password: secret
Port: 33060
```

When I connect with Sequel Pro, the homestead database is empty even when refreshed. I should be seeing the just created tables by the "migrate" command but I am not.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to see through what happened. I have not seen any documentation change to Vagrant 2.2.6 but I believe the default ports were changed. I reviewed the installation logs as:

```
==> -homestead-8: Forwarding ports...
    -homestead-8: 80 (guest) => 2201 (host) (adapter 1)
    -homestead-8: 443 (guest) => 2202 (host) (adapter 1)
    -homestead-8: 3306 (guest) => 2203 (host) (adapter 1)  //this is now 2203 from 33060
    -homestead-8: 4040 (guest) => 2204 (host) (adapter 1)
    -homestead-8: 5432 (guest) => 2205 (host) (adapter 1)
    -homestead-8: 8025 (guest) => 2206 (host) (adapter 1)
    -homestead-8: 27017 (guest) => 2207 (host) (adapter 1)
    -homestead-8: 22 (guest) => 2208 (host) (adapter 1)
```

I changed port 33060 forwarded from 3306 to the new 2203. it is now working fine.